# Program is not taking input from user

Tags: java, string, input, inputstream

This is java Program I am trying the user should enter the name but program is just printing the line Enter Name of Student and no cin

```
System.out.println("\n\t\tAdd at least 5 members to Start the Game");   
System.out.println("\n\t\tEnter Name Of Student = ");
String name=input.nextLine();
```

Comment: what does "no cin" mean?

Comment: did you use scanner?

Comment: yes i am using Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: No cin means the program is jumping to the next line, as per code it should take input from the user, but it is not taking input.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use scanner like

```
System.out.println("\n\t\tAdd at least 5 members to Start the Game");   
System.out.println("\n\t\tEnter Name Of Student = ");

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String studentName = scanner.nextLine();
```

Refer to this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-console-input-output) for more details and other options

Comment: This is working perfectly Thanks for sharing. As i have defined the Scanner in main program and inside the case 1 of switch i declared another variable in which i am taking input from user. can i get know why my code is not working?

Comment: You didn’t mentioned scanner in your question.  You need to share detailed code to understand the root cause. Can you share the reason for down voting?